# PYTHON How to check if a line contains specific letters and if not print the line

Tags: python, string, file, text

I have a text file with lots of data in.
I am trying to read the file line by line, and check if any of the letters in each line are letters in the word "hello".

Then I would like to print any line that does not contain either an h,e,l,l,o

My text file is called data.txt

Here is more code so far:

```
hello = list('hello')
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file.readlines:
    for line in file:
        if hello not in line:
            print(line)
```

but currently line 3 produces the error; NameError: name 'file' is not defined

**update:**

```
hello = list('hello')
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = set(line)
        if all(i not in s for i in hello):
            print(line)
```

Thank you for the help, now lots of lines of the text file have been eliminated, however "Epping" still prints, which has an "e" in it, as does the word "hello" and therefore it should be excluded?

Comment: `all([letter not in line for letter in hello])` Anyway replace `file.readlines` with `file` because that is why you are getting the error

Comment: @MooingRawr I'm trying to read each line in the text file..(not successfully!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening your file wrong.

```
hello = list('hello')
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = set(line)
        if all(letter not in s for letter in hello):
            print(line)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this I have primarily adapted my code based on your advice, however please see my most reason update :)

Comment: @Pythonnewbie `e` and `E` are different characters. To ignore case, do `s=set(line.lower())`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the correct usage of "with". Try this:

```
with open('<filename>') as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

If you just want ANY of the letters to appear (not all), you can use set intersection:

```
hello_set = set('hello')
for line in f:
    if not set(line).intersection(hello_set):
        print line
```

or use the "any" function:

```
for line in f:
    s = set(line)
    if any(letter not in s for letter in hello):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am researching intersection now because I haven't come across it before. :)

Answer (score -1):

You had a couple of small bugs in your code.  I fixed them, please compare.

```
hello = list('hello')
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      if all(letter not in line for letter in "hello"):
            print(line)
```

Comment: I think he's looking if the letters `h e l o` are in the line, not the string `hello`

Comment: read the question carefully "Then I would like to print any line that does not contain either an h,e,l,l,o"

Comment: Yeah i missed that part - just read -" and check if any of the letters in each line are letters in the word "hello". " Edit- fixed.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @PatrickHaugh Yes I'm trying to see if any character's within the word "hello" are in any line within the text file. If a line contains no "h","e","l" or "o', then It should print the line :)